# How to create the list view in salesforce

Tags: list-view

I have created a New List view in customer meeting object ,My Customer meeting object records.The list view have to show all the records which is created by current user logged in salesforce

Suppose a system administator logged in salesforce,if i choose my customer meeting object records it have to show all the records which has created by system administrator.

[image]

The value should not be hard coded,The list view will be visible to all users,**what filter condition  i have to give for the showing current logged user created records?Is there any possible way to acheive this?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a formula field to the custom object

```
Type checkbox
Is_Created_by_Running_User__c
formula: CreatedById = $User.Id
```

Then your filter in the listview is

```
Is_Created_by_Running_User__c = TRUE
```